# How to set host on pydevd.py from within eclipse pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

One can modify the host used to connect the debuger 
here:

https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/blob/master/pydevd.py#L2127

But I wonder if there is a 'clean' way to do this using Eclipse UI to configure this pydev setting ?

Comment: It's not expected that you edit the host at that point... Can you give more details on what you want to accomplish?

Comment: The goal is to connect to pydev debugger while running the code inside a docker container.

Comment: For that you should start the remote debugger on the Eclipse side and then use pydevd.settrace with the proper host/port. See http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html for details.